# How to geocode an area and determine if a set of points fall in that area

Tags: c#, .net, geocoding

Here's basically what I would like to do

- Outline a geographic area say a city for instance, and then persist this data
- Take a set of geopoints (lat,long) and 'query' or search or calculate whatever and determine which location(s) the points are in.

Is this even possible and if yes how? Thanks alot for your contributions guys

p.s. I am working in c# so any code snippets or libraries along those lines will be appreciated

Comment: yes, it's possible. there are sample applications from microsoft that provide this functionality ...

Comment: Thanks Xander, can you post some links and I'll be sure to mark your response as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to persist then look at SQL.  It has a spatial types and queries.

[Spatial Data (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)

In .NET have this but it is 4.5 and new to me.

[System.Data.Spatial Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506209)

The terms to search on are spatial and geography